# Create dynamic page & url from JSON in NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, json

I’m trying to create a page that displays  data within a JSON file, as well as uses the url relevant to the record in the url path.

I’m using html for the static structure and nodeJS for connecting with the JSON file and displaying the data.

The flow I’m working towards:

- User views page and clicks on a div that is surrounded by an .
- The  is using the “exampleURL” data from the output.json file, which is /example/example-retyu
- The “exampleURL” will be unique to each record within the output.json file
- User will be taken to /example/example-retyu page, where additional information will be shown relevant to that record.

What is the best way to create this flow?

I’ve looked at expressJS docs and a few other forum pages for support, but haven’t found the right answer yet.

Comment: https://github.com/jaycrav3ns/misc_scripts/blob/main/JS/json2html.zip This reads JSON to HTML via `handlebars` template and NodeJS.  It's similar, may be a possible starting point.